# Isn't deanonymization by having the entry and exit nodes in the same country a threat?

Tags: security, deanonymization, location

Consider the following scenario.

I live in a repressive state A. On the other hand, the citizens of state A operate many Tor nodes.

I am trying to call for demonstrations and criticize policies on domestic social networking sites in order to oppose the oppressive state A. However, these actions are banned in state A. And the State A investigative agency is trying to identify and arrest me.

Let us consider the following circuit that was constructed when I used Tor to post on the domestic SNS.

```
Country A node(entry) ⇒ Any middle node ⇒ Country A node(exit)
```

In this situation, can state A perform a correlated attack through the domestic ISP and de-anonymize as well as global passive adversary?

I found a [related question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/19841/34592), but this does not answer my question. This is because, even if the nodes are not operated by the same person, a correlated attack can be realistic by monitoring ISP traffic if the nodes are in the same country.